# detector in logic gate design

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, logic-gates, detector

1.regarding to logic gate concept i have to design the circuit with 4 bits multiple of 3 detector.
 but when i trying to make logic gate and  truth table it seems to me it's wrong so  i have no idea  how can i do design  circuit with 4 bits multiple 3 detector with truth table and circuit shape.
2.what actually detector do in logic gates and what is the affection of that on truth table?
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want? I'm guessing a '4 bits multiple of 3 detector' is a circuit that outputs high when the input is a multiple of 3?

Comment: Following @Felthry's question, is this a 'detect the numbers 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15' circuit?

Comment: This isn't, try with 0011... It gives out 0

Comment: the  outputs high when the input is a multiple of 3

Comment: How are you drawing the truth table?

Comment: Do you know Kharnaug Maps?

Comment: @Simus994 - You mean Karnaugh maps?

Comment: Yes, *Karnaugh, sorry.

Comment: no.after you said how to i have to put 1 Which of those numbers are 3 multiples like 0,3,6,9,12,15 in truth table.continue then i draw the  Karnaugh maps corresponding to truth table then i get function to draw the shape of circuit.thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to write down the truth table, get the logic function f(x1,x2,x3,x4) and minimize (if possible, but I think in this case is not) it with the Karnaugh Maps method. Then you can draw down the circuit using some AND ports (with 4 inputs) and a OR port (with 6 inputs if the f() is not minizable). Let's try.

Edit: I say 6 inputs because you have 6 multiples of 3 in 0-15 range

Comment: that was in my mind but how to find out the output in truth table?as you know we write  the Kharnaug Maps corresponding to the row which we have 1 as out put.this my main problem i don't know where is 1 in truth table

Comment: If you have 4 inputs you can have 16 binary combination that correspond to 16 numbers, from 0 to 15. Which of those numbers are 3 multiples? 0,3,6,9,12,15. You have to put 1 for all this numbers. And 0 for others obviously...